# VS Code "command": "make" differs from command line `make` in terminal window

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-code

I installed VS Code for Linux some time ago, opened a C ++ project in the workspace, created `tasks.json` - in general I did everything according to Google.

When I run the `make` command in a terminal window, everything is OK. But when I do the same (Ctrl+Shift+B) from VS Code I get an error.

Processing my `Makefile` terminates after the command `libtool: link: c++  -fPIC -DPIC -shared -nostdlib /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o ....`

with message
`c++: error: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o: No such file or directory`.

Of course, the path is correct (and is good when I use the command line `make` in a terminal window).

Contents of `tasks.json` is trivial (same as in microsoft.com):

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "ClanLib",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "make",
        // start the build without prompting for task selection, use "group": "build" otherwise
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "presentation": {
            "echo": true,
            "reveal": "always",
            "focus": false,
            "panel": "shared"
        },
        // arg passing example: in this case is executed make QUIET=0
        "args": ["QUIET=0"],
        // Use the standard less compilation problem matcher.
        "problemMatcher": {
            "owner": "cpp",
            "fileLocation": ["absolute"],
            "pattern": {
                "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
                "file": 1,
                "line": 2,
                "column": 3,
                "severity": 4,
                "message": 5
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

I can't post `Makefile`, it consists of thousands of lines of code after autogeneration from https://github.com/sphair/ClanLib...

Please help with setting up Visual Studio Code (Linux Mint).

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Please provide more content from your tasks.json and of the makefile. What you give is not enough information for us to know what might be going wrong.

Comment: Have you already installed [libc6-dev](https://askubuntu.com/a/839163)?

Comment: Tezirg - please see my updated post.
Ayak973 - obviously not installed but from command line all is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is here
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/62532

Thanks for mr. @jerch

> you have different build sets installed, see "GNU Make 4.1" vs. "GNU Make 4.2.1". For some reason /bin/sh defaults to the other one. To fix that you have to consult your distro's help (in Ubuntu you can switch buildsets with the update-alternatives command).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you try build manually with your makefile within a directory, and vscode from another.
If it is the case, you can tell your tasks to run from a specific directory with the `cwd` option - [doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks):

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format

    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "ClanLib",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "make",

            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/<DIR_WITH_MAKEFILE>"
            }
            ...
}]}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not help, everything is correct with directories. The VS Code displays at the first line `> Executing task in folder ClanLib: make QUIET=0 <` and this is the correct directory.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I felt something. In the terminal window inside VSCode I see

```
 sh-4.4$ help
 GNU bash, версия 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
```

But in the OS terminal:

```
art@artPC:~/git/ClanLib$ help
GNU bash, версия 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

The difference is **-unknown-** and **-pc-**. Result of `whoami` is the same on both terminals.

And finally in VSCode terminal:

```
sh-4.4$ ls
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

Name of symbolic-link `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` is defferent between OS and VSCode. Bug of VSCode?